# Soap request for GetListItems webservices for iphone development

Tags: iphone, sharepoint, soap

I am developing an iphone application for soap request for sharePoint i.e GetListItems web services. But I am getting different types of exceptions and i am very new to iphone and also soap request ..

Error is :-- "`Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).`"

And my xml code is :--

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \n"
                         "<soap:Body> \n"
                         "<GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">\n"
                         "<listName>@""</listName>\n"
                         "<viewName>string</viewName>\n"
                         "<query></query>\n"
                         "<viewFields></viewFields>\n"
                         "<rowLimit></rowLimit>\n"
                         "<queryOptions></queryOptions>\n"
                         "<webID></webID>\n"
                         "</GetListItems>\n"
                         "</soap:Body> \n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>"];
```

I cannot find out where is the problem please help me..

Answer (score 0):

"Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)." usually means an issue with the value in the listName node. This takes either the display name or the GUID (without brackets) of the list you're querying from.

Is what you pasted the actual request you're sending right now? Cause that will blow up.

Comment: Hi

    Thank u for your quick replying .Yes i am putting 32 digits for viewName .. But i am sending blank for listName. So need i to put 32 digits for listname ? please send me if you have sample application soap requet for Iphone Application development.

Thanks & Regrads,
KamalBhr

Answer (score 0):

the listName element should be the GUID for the list
'{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}'
be sure to include the single quotes.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, our SharePoint instance had two sub-sites.  I was not querying the right site by URL.  I could query by the list GUID on the "wrong" site, but when I updated my URL to point to the right subsite, it found the list without issue.